# SQL query - Finding the max value of an attribute without a subquery

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the relation Book with the following simple schema

```
Book(title, pages)
```

I want to find the title(s) of the book(s) with the highest number of pages, 
but without using a subquery.

Is this possible?

EDIT: This is not for a particular DBMS. I'm studying from a book (which uses the SQL-99 Standard) and this is a part from an exercise.

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? And why don't you want to use a subquery?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and your attempt with a subquery.

Comment: Please define ***subquery***. Are you intending a syntactical or functional interpretation of the phrase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an `except`. You find all the books that have another one with more pages (lower part) and then you search all the books except those ones.

```
    select title,pages
      from books
   Except --minus if Oracle
   select b1.title,b1.pages
     from books b1 join books b2 
       on b1.pages < b2.pages
```

Comment: @Paparazzi no subquery I guess. I wouldn't use this on any project of course, but I think it might be the answer Da Mike is looking for. Also, I learnt this trick on an online DB course (after I thought I knew a lot about SQL)

Comment: No probs, good answer as standard SQL, meets the requirement for ties and indisputably no sub queries in sight by anyone's reckoning.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top (1) with ties title, pages
from books  
order by pages desc
```

[select top](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . This is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Simple enough to replace `SELECT TOP (1) ...` with `SELECT ... OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROW`.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Simple enough but would not a be a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

This is typically solved using a window function

```
select title, pages
from (
  select title, pages, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by title order by pages desc) as rnk
  from books
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

However the above is SQL:2003 not SQL99. You can also re-write this to use a common table expression:

```
with ranked as (
   select title, pages, 
          dense_rank() over (partition by title order by pages desc) as rnk
   from books
)
select *
from ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

If you consider derived tables or common table expressions a "sub-query" then (in standard SQL) you could also limit the number of rows:

```
select title, pages
from books
order by pages desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

If two books have the same number of maximum pages, then this will however only show one of them, whereas the other two solutions will show both.

Comment: I think most people would call that a sub query

Comment: @Paparazzi: but it's called a derived table it's not a sub-query (you could e.g. rewrite it to use a common table expression to make it more obvious)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [`<derived table> ::= <table subquery>`](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/26/sql-subqueries-and-derived-tables/)

Comment: And I would call a CTE a subquery.

Comment: @MartinSmith: quote from the SQL standard: "*A table is either a base table, a derived table, a transient table, or a viewed table [..] A transient table is a named table that may come into existence implicitly during the evaluation of a <query expression> or the execution of a trigger. A transient table is identified by a <query name> if it arises during the evaluation of a <query expression>*" Chapter 4.14.2,  Types of tables

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but according to the grammar is it possible to define a `<derived table>` without a `<table subquery>`?